# Как выбрать Main class в конфигурации проекта?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

У меня не выбирается `Main` `class`, автоматически ничего не подтягивается, при выборе вручную кнопка `ОК` неактивна, при вводе пути к классу строка подсвечивается красным шрифтом. Как быть и что делать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Idea` пока ещё не знает, что в указанной папке находятся классы `Java`. Можно указать это самому правой кнопкой мыши:

**ПКМ** ⇒ **Mark Directory as** ⇒ **Sources Root**

Либо можно указать это в настройках проекта:

[image: Project Structure]